# parallel in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, 7zip

I had a directory which contains ~200k files, I want to find corrupt/malformed zip/RAR files quickly

here is simple bash script we wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/xyz/"
for filename in $(ls $path)

do
output=:$(7za t $path$filename);
if  echo "$output" | grep -q "Everything is Ok"; then
    echo "MATCH"
        else 
        echo "NOK_FILE:$filename"
fi


done;
```

so testing ~200k files taking about ~14h to complete in sequential, so we need run parallel check, in the `for` loop

I need to finish up the check in ~10minitues

I tried lots of ways mentioned in StackOverflow but I can't find a good way

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: You can use GNU Parallel to execute multiple cases in parallel.

Comment: The bottleneck is probably reading all the files from disk, it's unlikely that there's any way to speed it up 100x.

Comment: You can reduce the number of processes created and improve the correctness of your code: `for file in "$path"/*; do output="$(7za t "$file")"; case "$output" in *"Everything is Ok"*) echo "MATCH";; *) echo "NOK_FILE:$file";; esac`

Comment: @melpomene i got this error `line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @user3325376 Just add `; done` to the end of that snippet, as in `esac; done`

Comment: @user3325376 As long as we're shaving milliseconds, try `case "$(7za t "$file")" in`

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, but using answer field for better formatting.  This doesn't address your question, but you could clean up your script a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/xyz/
for filename in $path/*;  do
    if 7za t "$filename" | grep -q "Everything is Ok"; then
        echo "MATCH"
    else 
        echo "NOK_FILE:$filename"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Quote the filename

Comment: If you use `case` instead of `if` + `grep`, you don't need to spawn a new process.